# Bash alias not found stuck on my terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

I was trying to make my Ubuntu connect to nexus tab and used the following command lines:

```
echo "alias android-connect=\"mtpfs -o allow_other /media/GalaxyNexus\"" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "alias android-disconnect=\"fusermount -u /media/GalaxyNexus\"" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

I got the following errors and every time I open my command line it's writt

```
bash: alias: -o: not found
bash: alias: allow_other: not found
bash: alias: /media/Nexus: not found
bash: alias: -u: not found
bash: alias: /media/Nexus: not found
bash: alias: source: not found
bash: alias: /home/user/.bashrc: not found
```

How can I handle that?

Comment: Can you `cat` your `.bashrc` and paste the added lines here?

Comment: Something doesn't quite add up here - your alias has the path /media/GalaxyNexus, and yet the error message has /media/Nexus.
But somehow it seems the double quotes must be missing from the line in `.bashrc`. Best way would be to manually edit it in gedit (or similar) rather than echoing to it, I'd say - that way you can make sure it's parsing correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your `.bashrc` file contains the lines without the double quotes:

```
alias android-connect=mtpfs -o allow_other /media/GalaxyNexus
alias android-disconnect=fusermount -u /media/GalaxyNexus
```

Open the file in an editor and remove the offending lines.

Comment: Or just quote them.... `alias short="some commands"`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem due to a missing closing quote - ". The best way to figure out the problem is to open the file in a graphical editor which has syntax coloring. I did it using **sublime text**